# IntelliJ IDEA / DataGrip: SQL border highlighting of current statement

Tags: intellij-idea, colors, datagrip

I installed a color theme yesterday and lost a border that before surrounded the SQL statement I was working on. It's the purple border surrounding the query in the image.

[image]

I searched but couldn't find the setting where the color for this is defined. Does anyone know where how I can get this border back? I'm thinking the theme I installed either changed the color of this border or just fully disabled it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the **Bordered** and the color for Effects in Settings (Preferences on OS X) | Editor | Colors & Fonts | Database settings for **Statement to execute** entry:[image]

Note that you can open relevant to the place in Editor Color Settings via **Jump to Colors and Fonts** action (Ctrl(Cmd)+Shift+A popup):[image]

Comment: That seems like an obvious location, can't believe I haven't found it. Thanks for the Jump to Colors and Fonts tip aswell!

Answer (score 2):

In the 2020.3 version it's under `Settings > Editor > Color Scheme > Database`

On the right menu, you can uncheck `Console > Statement to Execute` effects.